# Не работает анимация в сафари

Tags: css

```css
@keyframes pulse {
  25% {
    -webkit-transform: scale(1.1);
    -moz-transform: scale(1.1);
    -ms-transform: scale(1.1);
    -o-transform: scale(1.1);
    transform: scale(1.1);
  }

  75% {
    -webkit-transform: scale(0.9);
    -moz-transform: scale(0.9);
    -ms-transform: scale(0.9);
    -o-transform: scale(0.9);
    transform: scale(0.9);
  }
}
.arrow-down {
  display: block;
  width: 28px;
  height: 28px;
  background: red ;
  -webkit-border-radius: 50%;
  -moz-border-radius: 50%;
  border-radius: 50%;
  position: relative;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  
  -webkit-transform: translateZ(0);;
  -moz-transform: translateZ(0);;
  -ms-transform: translateZ(0);;
  -o-transform: translateZ(0);;
  transform: translateZ(0);;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
  -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
  box-shadow: 0 0 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
  -webkit-animation: pulse 1s linear infinite;
  -o-animation: pulse 1s linear infinite;
  animation: pulse 1s linear infinite;
  }
```

```html
      <a href="#slider" class="arrow-down"></a>
```

префиксы использовал но анимации нету. Как исправить?
Добавил @-webkit-keyframes теперь анимация работает через раз. Тоесть  захожу на страницу анимации нету, обновляю раза 2 она появляется, опять обновил и она пропала

Comment: какая версия сафари https://caniuse.com/#search=keyframes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Короче в сафари какой-то баг или что-то еще если в keyframes не указано 100% то она не всегда срабатывает
Вот рабочий вариант

```css
@-webkit-keyframes pulse {
  25% {
    -webkit-transform: scale(1.1);
    -moz-transform: scale(1.1);
    -ms-transform: scale(1.1);
    -o-transform: scale(1.1);
    transform: scale(1.1);
  }


  75% {
    -webkit-transform: scale(0.9);
    -moz-transform: scale(0.9);
    -ms-transform: scale(0.9);
    -o-transform: scale(0.9);
    transform: scale(0.9);
  }
  100% {

  }

}
@keyframes pulse {
  25% {
    -webkit-transform: scale(1.1);
    -moz-transform: scale(1.1);
    -ms-transform: scale(1.1);
    -o-transform: scale(1.1);
    transform: scale(1.1);
  }

  75% {
    -webkit-transform: scale(0.9);
    -moz-transform: scale(0.9);
    -ms-transform: scale(0.9);
    -o-transform: scale(0.9);
    transform: scale(0.9);
  }
  100% {

  }
}
.arrow-down {
  display: block;
  width: 28px;
  height: 28px;
  background: red ;
  -webkit-border-radius: 50%;
  -moz-border-radius: 50%;
  border-radius: 50%;
  position: relative;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  
  -webkit-transform: translateZ(0);;
  -moz-transform: translateZ(0);;
  -ms-transform: translateZ(0);;
  -o-transform: translateZ(0);;
  transform: translateZ(0);;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
  -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
  box-shadow: 0 0 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
  -webkit-animation: pulse 1s linear infinite;
  -o-animation: pulse 1s linear infinite;
  animation: pulse 1s linear infinite;
  }
```

```html
<a href="#" class="arrow-down"></a>
```